# Litepicker - automatically add the second date by selecting the first date

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I am using https://litepicker.com/ and trying to create the variable dateString to have both dates based on the start date being given.

Can anyone help me to see what I am doing wrong?

```
setup: (picker) => {
        picker.on('selected', (date1, endDate) => {
       endDate.setDate(date1.getDate() + 6);
        var dateString =   `${date1.format('D MMMM YYYY')} - ${endDate.format('D MMMM YYYY')}`;
        
        if (dateString == "20 June 2021 - 26 June 2021") {
```

Answer (score 0):

After several hours I have come up with the following which seems to work but if anyone can help me to improve the code please let me know.

```
setup: (picker) => {
    picker.on('selected', (date1, date2=> {
    var date2 = date1;
    var date4 = date1.format('D MMMM YYYY');
    var date2 = date2.add(6, 'days');
    var dateString =   ${date4} - ${date2.format('D MMMM YYYY')}`;
    document.getElementById("date").value = `${dateString}`;

if (dateString == "20 June 2021 - 26 June 2021") { `
```